# Append div onto elements that match JSON data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am looking to append divs onto Vanilla Calendar to show indicators that the day has an event on. I have my event information in a JSON file:

```
{
  "events": [{
      "2023-08": [{
          "2023-08-29": [{
              "eventID1": [{
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
              }]
            },
            {
              "eventID2": [{
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
              }]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "2023-08-30": [{
              "eventID1": [{
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
              }]
            },
            {
              "eventID2": [{
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
              }]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "2023-09": [{
          "2023-09-29": [{
              "eventID1": [{
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
              }]
            },
            {
              "eventID2": [{
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
              }]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "2023-09-30": [{
              "eventID1": [{
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
              }]
            },
            {
              "eventID2": [{
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
              }]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Each month of the calendar shows a data attribute on the div like this:

```
data-calendar-selected-month="7" //month 7 = August
```

Each day of the calendar shows a data attribute on the button like this:

```
data-calendar-day="2023-08-29"
```

```
<button class="vanilla-calendar-day__btn vanilla-calendar-day__btn_today" type="button" data-calendar-day="2023-08-29">29</button>
```

What I'm looking to do is for every day on the calendar, append a div onto that element on the page that matches the date within the JSON data... I am just unsure how to approach this with a lot of JSON data

Can someone detail how that loop might work?

I'm trying something like this:

```
eventData = data.events;
drawEvent(data)

function drawEvent(data) {
  for (events in data) {
    var eventEntries = data[*date?*]
    for (var i = 0; i < eventEntries.length; i++) {
      //append the div here?
    }
  }
}
```

Sorry for rough code, but I appreciate any help

Comment: You mention the data attributes are on a div, but you show them on a button. Which is it?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but to get the object in the current iteration of the loop you do `var eventEntries = data[events]`

Comment: If you want to find the DOM element for a specific date, use `document.querySelector("div[data-calendar-day='2023-08-29']")`. You can use a template literal to substitute the date from the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

That data is structured very strangely, including arrays and objects which always only have one item.

```js
let data = {
  "events": [{
      "2023-08": [{
          "2023-08-29": [{
              "eventID1": [{
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
              }]
            },
            {
              "eventID2": [{
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
              }]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "2023-08-30": [{
              "eventID1": [{
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
              }]
            },
            {
              "eventID2": [{
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
              }]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "2023-09": [{
          "2023-09-29": [{
              "eventID1": [{
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
              }]
            },
            {
              "eventID2": [{
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
              }]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "2023-09-30": [{
              "eventID1": [{
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
              }]
            },
            {
              "eventID2": [{
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
              }]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
let eventData = data.events;
for (const entry of eventData) {
  for (const [month, days] of Object.entries(entry)) {
    for (const dayObject of days) {
      for (const [day, events] of Object.entries(dayObject)) {
        let dayElement = document.querySelector(`[data-calendar-day="${day}"]`);
        for (const eventObject of events) {
          for (const [eventId, details] of Object.entries(eventObject)) {
            for (const event of details) {
              let div = document.createElement("div");
              div.append(event.title + ", " + event.category);
              dayElement.append(div);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="vanilla-calendar-day__btn vanilla-calendar-day__btn_today" type="button" data-calendar-day="2023-08-29">29</button>
<button class="vanilla-calendar-day__btn vanilla-calendar-day__btn_today" type="button" data-calendar-day="2023-08-30">30</button>
<button class="vanilla-calendar-day__btn vanilla-calendar-day__btn_today" type="button" data-calendar-day="2023-09-29">29</button>
<button class="vanilla-calendar-day__btn vanilla-calendar-day__btn_today" type="button" data-calendar-day="2023-09-30">30</button>
```

I would prefer it if the data looked like this instead:

```json
{
  "events": {
      "2023-08": {
          "2023-08-29": [
             {
                "id": "eventID1",
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
             },
             {
                "id": "eventID2",
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
             }
          ],
          "2023-08-30": [
             {
                "id": "eventID1",
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
             },
             {
                "id": "eventID2",
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
             }
          ]
      },
      "2023-09": {
          "2023-09-29": [
             {
                "id": "eventID1",
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
             },
             {
                "id": "eventID2",
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
             }
          ],
          "2023-09-30": [
             {
                "id": "eventID1",
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
             },
             {
                "id": "eventID2",
                "title": "Event Title",
                "category": "Category"
             }
          ]
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the matching element with the following loop. `targetElement` will be the div matching `data-calendar-day`.

```
for (let month of data.events) {
    for (let days of Object.values(month)) {
        for (let day of days) {
            for (let [date, events] of Object.entries(day)) {
                for (let event of events.map(it => Object.values(it)).flat(2)) {
                    const targetElement = document.querySelector(`[data-calendar-day="${date}"]`);
                    targetElement.textContent = `Title: ${event.title}. Category: ${event.category}`;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More information regarding [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).